# Which nodes will execute dataframe.write function?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, parquet, bigdata

When my program executes the dataframe.write function, which nodes will execute this function? The slave nodes will write the results to disk directly or it will send all the results to driver to let driver do this job?

Answer (score 1):

The worker nodes. Writing is distributed as is nearly all operations (except `collect`, `take`, `toPandas`, etc)